# Why is my MailKit/MimeKit code blowing up? Does MailKit support gmail and Oath2?

Tags: oauth-2.0, gmail, mailkit

Here is my code, which has a comment to show where an exception occurs. I have a working implementation using Google's APIs directly, but I would rather use MailKit is it is an much friendlier API and I'd like to support other providers, not just Google.

```cs
internal async Task GmailTestAsync()
{
    const string GMailAccount = "youraccount@gmail.com";

    var clientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
    {
        ClientId = "yourclientid",
        ClientSecret = "yourclientsecret",
    };

    var codeFlow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
    {
        DataStore = new FileDataStore("CredentialCacheFolder", false),
        // Scopes = new[] { "https://mail.google.com/" }, maybe this works?
        Scopes = new[] { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly, GmailService.Scope.GmailSend },
        ClientSecrets = clientSecrets
    });

    var codeReceiver = new LocalServerCodeReceiver();
    var authCode = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(codeFlow, codeReceiver);

    var credential = await authCode.AuthorizeAsync(GMailAccount, CancellationToken.None);

    if (credential.Token.IsExpired(SystemClock.Default))
        await credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None);

    var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(credential.UserId, credential.Token.AccessToken);

    using (var client = new ImapClient())
    {
        await client.ConnectAsync("imap.gmail.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);

        // next line throws exception
        await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2);
        /*
        MailKit.Security.AuthenticationException
            HResult=0x80131500
            Message=Authentication failed.
            Source=MailKit
            StackTrace:
            at MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient.<AuthenticateAsync>d__103.MoveNext()
            deleted...
        */
        await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
    }
}
```

Does MailKit support gmail and OAuth2? Is there some sample code somewhere? I have been following the code here: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/GMailOAuth2.md but I get a MailKit.Security.AuthenticationException at await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2);

Comment: Change the Scopes to the value in the MailKit documentation. You need precisely that scope because only that scope will work for IMAP, POP3 and SMTP. The scopes you are using only work with the HTTP REST API that the Google libraries use.